# Fake RAID (dmraid) not seeing new SATA drives

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, raid, storage, dmraid

I have three drives in my machine, one SSD with 32GB and two 1TB drives, attached to an *Intel 82801JI (ICH10) SATA AHCI Controller*. The problem is, that I can access only one of the 1TB drives when the other one is not plugged in. When it is plugged in I see the drives as sda and sdb, but there seem to be no partitions. Looking at these drives with cfdisk, the partitions are there, though.

Both of the 1TB drives are carrying a partition, being part of a software RAID1, created with mdadm.

Before I threw the SSD into the mix, the other two have been working fine.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with `dmraid -x`, which deletes all existing software RAIDs, so that the disks show up in `/dev` as usual.

Comment: I hope fake raid works out for you. It really doesn't add to performance and just limits your portability. Best reason to use it is a multi-boot situation with an OS that can't support mdraid (e.g. Windows). Good luck. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto